# How to pass import as props parameters in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lottie

I use react-lotties and i want to put differents animations in many div changing only the url of lotties

I am a react beginner, be kind please :)

this is my script :

- My lotties Component :

```
    import React, { Component } from "react"
    import Lottie from "react-lottie"
    import animationData from "./lotties1.json"
    import animationData from "./lotties2.json"
    import animationData from "./lotties3.json"
    import "./lotties.css"

    class LottiesC extends Component {
      render() {
        const defaultOptions = {
          loop: true,
          autoplay: true,
          animationData: animationData,
          rendererSettings: {
            preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice",
          },
        }

        return (
          <div className="x">
            <Lottie options={defaultOptions} height={600} width={600} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default LottiesC
```

-My index.js Component:

```
       import React from "react"
        import Navigation from "../components/Navigation"
        import LottieControl from "../components/LottiesC"

        const index = () => {
          return (
            <section className="index">
              <div><LottiesC animationData ={lotties 1}  /> </div>
               <div><LottiesC  animationData ={lotties 2} /> </div>
              <div><LottiesC animationData ={lotties 3}  /> </div>
            </section>
          )
        }

        export default index
```

Comment: ES6 module imports cannot be changed at runtime. What you want to do is pass a prop indicating which animation to use, such as `useAnimation="1"` and then based on that prop set the `animationPart` of options' object of your component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by @Dellirium you should be passing different values over props to your components.

Here is how it works:

```js
const animationDatas = [
  { id: 'first' },
  { id: 'second' },
  { id: 'third' },
];

class LottiesC extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const defaultOptions = {
      // loop: true,
      // autoplay: true,
      animationData: this.props.animationData,
      // rendererSettings: {
      //  preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice",
      // },
    }

    return (
      <div className="x">
        {/** <Lottie options={defaultOptions} height={600} width={600} /> **/}
        {JSON.stringify(defaultOptions)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <section className="index">
      <div><LottiesC animationData={animationDatas[0]}  /></div>
       <div><LottiesC  animationData={animationDatas[1]} /></div>
      <div><LottiesC animationData={animationDatas[2]} /></div>
    </section>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```